# Form created dynamically always gets 403 forbidden on a django rest framework api POST

Tags: javascript, django, csrf

I have multiple text posts on my website. On clicking the edit button I dynamically create a form replacing the div to a form element. I have my POST api set up on the django side to get this form submit and edit the existing post. But my POST request always gets 403. First i assumed not having a csrf token is causing the problem. So i edited my js code to this-

```
                    //form create
                    const post_content_element = post.querySelector('div .text-content');
                    const post_content = post_content_element.innerHTML;

                    let edit_form = document.createElement('form');

                    // Here I added the csrf token as a hidden input 
                    let inputElem = document.createElement('input');
                    inputElem.type = 'hidden';
                    inputElem.name = 'csrfmiddlewaretoken';
                    inputElem.value = '{{ csrf_token }}';
                    edit_form.appendChild(inputElem);

                    edit_form.setAttribute('id', 'edit-form');
                    edit_form.setAttribute('method', 'POST');

                    let text_content = document.createElement('input');
                    text_content.setAttribute('type', 'textarea');
                    text_content.setAttribute('id', 'edit-content');
                    text_content.value = post_content;

                    let submit = document.createElement('input');
                    submit.setAttribute('type', 'submit');
                    submit.setAttribute('id', 'edit-submit');

                    edit_form.appendChild(text_content);
                    edit_form.appendChild(submit);
```

still it gets 403 forbidden. My api looks like this-

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def edit_post(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        # do something
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

Please note I am using my User(AbstractUser) model for authentication. I am out of ideas. What could be the other reasons for this problem?

Comment: Please share your full code of `edit_post` view

Comment: Also, please check your server logs to check exactly what does the 403 error refer to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by reading this-  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/csrf/#ajax

The getCookie function as seen on the above page

```
function getCookie(name) {
            var cookieValue = null;
            if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== '') {
                var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
                for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
                    var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
                    // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
                    if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === (name + '=')) {
                        cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            return cookieValue;}
```

then I wrote the POST request with X-CSRFToken header as like below-

```
fetch(window.location.origin.concat('<url>'), {
                            method:'POST',

                            credentials: 'same-origin',
                            headers: {
                                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                                "X-CSRFToken": getCookie("csrftoken")
                            },
                           body: <whatever body you have>
                           })
```